# How to disable transactions in ABP Framework?

Tags: abp

I want to turn off the transaction in my ABP project.

Is there any way to turn off transactions?

Answer (score 1):

To completely disable the DB transactions, you can add the following code in the `ConfigureServices()` method of `EntityFrameworkCore` project.

```cs
Configure<Volo.Abp.Uow.AbpUnitOfWorkDefaultOptions>(options =>
{
    options.TransactionBehavior = Volo.Abp.Uow.UnitOfWorkTransactionBehavior.Disabled;
});
```

[image]